# How can I post all selected items to web server when I use NanoHTTPD in Android?

Tags: android, jquery, nanohttpd

I use NanoHTTPD as web server in my android, the following content is generated and I can browse the html in Firefox.

I hope to delete all selected items, I don't know how to write jQuery or JavaScript code to post the file names of all selected items  to web server

and I don't know how NanoHTTPD handle get the posted file names.

Could you write some sample code for me? Thanks!

```
<input name="subBox" type="checkbox"  value="\SD\1.jpg"/>1.jpg <br/>
<input name="subBox" type="checkbox"  value="\SD\2.jpg"/>2.jpg <br/>
<input name="subBox" type="checkbox"  value="\SD\3.jpg"/>3.jpg <br/>
<input name="subBox" type="checkbox"  value="\SD\4.jpg"/>4.jpg <br/>
.
.
.

<input type="button" value="Delete Selected Images" onclick="DeleteSelectedImage()" />
```

Comment: `of all selected items to web server`. To which webserver? And who is posting?

Comment: `name="subBox" ` Only one `input` for thst name possible.

Comment: Just let FireFox post the form. Then in your webserver look for the checked values.  You dont need javascript or jquery.

Comment: To  greenapps: Could you give a sample code to post the form and let webserver to look the checked values?

Comment: `sample code to post the form`. You did not listen. I said 'let FireFox post the form'. No code needed for posting.

Comment: Well of course you need a normal submit button and not use an onclick handler for it.

Comment: Thanks! How can  NanoHTTPD web server look for the checked values?

Comment: And more , I think I can set one name for all  checkbox  controls.

Comment: There is a `parameters` parameter in the `serve()` method of NanoHttpD. You need different checkbox names to begin with `subBox1, subBox2,..`

Comment: Thanks! The user can modify the name of a checkbox in client using javascript, so I think it's not a good way to look for  the checked values based control name.

Comment: And more, if there are many checkbox controls, how can you know the amount of the  checkbox controls? subBox_ID1, subBox_ID2, subBox_ID3,  ... subBox_IDn

Comment: You can check if a key exists in the keyset. In the Map.

Comment: Letting the user change the name of an input looks like a bad idea. Only values is enough i think.

Comment: You could start with just logging or printing all key =value pairs of the Map parameters.

Comment: Thanks! if you don't make sure the amount of the checkbox controls, how can you look for all  checkbox controls?

Comment: Just start with printing all key value pairs and you will get usefull ideas.